# Intellij Log4j core dependency download failing

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, log4j

I am using maven 3.6.3 with IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 (Ultimate). Here is my pom.xml for a spring-boot library project I am currently working.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.pickme</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-etcd-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>etcd-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <jetcd.version>0.5.8</jetcd.version>
</properties>
```

And when trying to `mvn clean install`, dependency download fails with this error. `log4j-api` resolves without any errors but the `log4j-core` and `log4j-slf4j-impl` doesn't seem to download.

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:pom:2.14.1 
from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
Transfer failed for 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.14.1/log4j-core-2.14.1.pom
```

Edit:
In IntelliJ IDEA settings these are the Maven Repositories.
[maven settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKNjc.png)
And all the links are accessible through my browser without any issue.

Warnings from idea.log

```
2021-11-04 16:01:32,805 [3353406]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Scanning of spring-boot-etcd-starter uses 7 scanning threads 
2021-11-04 16:01:32,836 [3353437]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get compatible updates from Marketplace: Remote host terminated the handshake 
2021-11-04 16:01:33,017 [3353618]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get JetBrains plugins' IDs from Marketplace: Remote host terminated the handshake 
2021-11-04 16:01:33,026 [3353627]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get JetBrains plugins' IDs from Marketplace: Remote host terminated the handshake 
2021-11-04 16:01:33,036 [3353637]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get JetBrains plugins' IDs from Marketplace: Remote host terminated the handshake 
2021-11-04 16:01:33,127 [3353728]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get JetBrains plugins' IDs from Marketplace: Remote host terminated the handshake 
2021-11-04 16:01:33,176 [3353777]   WARN - arketplace.MarketplaceRequests - Can not get JetBrains plugins' IDs from Marketplace: Remote host terminated the handshake
```

And some exceptions on the stacktrace

```
Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

Comment: Does `mvn clean compile` work from the command line? Do you have proxies in network? Any errors in [idea.log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory)?

Comment: What is between you and the internet part where Maven Central is located?  Corporate Firewall?  Maven repository infrastructure inhouse?

Comment: I am not using any proxy between me and the Maven Central. mvn clean compile also outputs the same error.